# Django select where field is the concatenation of a string and column value

Tags: mysql, sql, django, orm

I'm trying to select a row where a field is the concatenation of a string and column value.  This was the closest I could get:

```
qs = Report.objects.filter(job=self, persona__identity="u" + F("user__id"))
```

Report has fields persona and user.  A persona object contains an identity field that is the concatenation of an identifier and an id.  I'm trying to get all reports where the persona's identity string matches the user referenced by the report.  (Note these are not my actual table names...everything changed to protect the innocent.)

This produces a query like,

```
WHERE (`persona`.`identity` =  u + `report`.`user_id` AND ...
```

but what I really need is something like

```
WHERE (`persona`.`identity` =  CONCAT("u", `report`.`user_id`) AND ...
```

Is there a way to do this with the ORM?

Comment: Have you considedered changing Persona.identity to reular FK to user table (instead of 'u'+id)? This is recommended IMO if you want to provide data integrity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `extra` to define the lookup in raw SQL. Something like:

```
Report.objects.extra({
  where=['(`persona`.`identity` = CONCAT("u", `report`.`user_id`)']
})
```

There are some downsides to using raw SQL, such as the code not being portable across different DB engines, but for complex queries, it is far more expressive than trying to shoehorn a solution into the ORM.

Comment: got it! thanks.  i ended up needing to do Report.objects.select_related().extra(...) so that it would correctly perform the join, but this worked!

Comment: Glad I could help. Dropping into raw SQL has its drawbacks, but for cases like this, there's sometimes no alternative.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative is available in Django 1.8:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Report.objects.filter(persona__identity=Concat(Value('u'), 'user__id'))
```